# when select JPA tree, childNodes is always null

Tags: jpa, tree

I'm trying to select tree structure using JPQL. Mapping works a bit different than I expected. It maps tree structure to parent but List childNodes is always null :( Here is my mapping:

```
@Entity
@NamedQueries({
      @NamedQuery(name = "TreeNode.findAllTree", 
              query = "select p from TreeNode p  " +
                    "LEFT JOIN fetch p.parentNode"),
    })
public class TreeNode {
    @Id
    private long id = 0; 

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "parent_id")
    public TreeNode parentNode;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="parentNode")
    public List<TreeNode> childNodes;
```

Here is query:

```
List<TreeNode> list = super.getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("TreeNode.findAllTree").getResultList();
```

Here is my table data:

```
 ID, PARENT_ID
  1      NULL
  2         1
  3         1
  4         3
```

I've tried eager and lazy FetchType but childNodes is always null ;( Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Odd. What JPA provider and version are you using?

If you remove the join fetch, do you get the children?
What SQL is executed for the children?

When you set the parent for a node, do you also add the child?  If you don't then the parent with no children could be cache in your EntityManager, does a refresh get the children?